# Как в java hibernate создать колонку в бд, если она остутсвует

Tags: java, веб-программирование, hibernate, jpa

Проблема вот в чём. У меня есть класс

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
```

со своими свойствами (колонками в БД). Сейчас появилась необходимость добавить новое свойство (newProperty). После того, как я прописываю его в классе и снова запускаю приложение, возникает ошибка column user0_.newProperty does not exist. Единственное решение, которое я нашел, это перед запуском приложения вручную добавить нову колонку в бд, а после этого запускать. Но такое решение абсолютно меня не устраивает. Каким образом можно проаннотировать (или как-то еще прописать), чтобы несуществующая колонка в бд сперва создавалась, а потом уже шло обращение к ней.

Comment: Если у Вас Spring Boot, то достаточно в `application.properties` добавить параметр `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`. 

Подробнее в документации: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

В **persistence.xml** необходимо добавить строку:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

После чего Hibernate будет добавлять колонки в таблицу, если вы добавите поле в POJO объект (Необходимо перегрузить ваше приложение)